# How to specify a different main class when running a scala jar on the command line?

Tags: scala

I have a scala project with 2 objects that extend `App`. I have specified one as the main class in `build.sbt`. I'm using `assembly` to build a fat jar.

How can I execute the non-default main class when running the jar on the command line? I.e. if `com.example.app1` is specified as the main class in `build.sbt`, how could I run `com.example.app2` from the command line using the jar (assuming that also extends `App`)?

This will be in a production environment where I won't have `sbt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You run the default main class (from the jar's manifest) like this:

```
java -jar assembly.jar
```

And you would run a different main class like this:

```
java -cp assembly.jar com.example.app2
```